# jQuery toggle one class when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write an if else statement to trigger one class when another one is clicked under the condition that the one class has a marginTop of -200px.

I tried using this if statement but it doesn't work:

```
    if ($('.logintrigger').click() && $('.register').css('marginTop') === '-200px') {
        $('.registertrigger').toggle(
            function () {$('.register').stop().animate({'marginTop':'-0px'},200); $('#opencloseregister').css({'backgroundPosition':'-20px 0px'});}
        );
    }
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a jsfiddle with an example of proper ifelse with jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/RQ75m/

```
$(".logintrigger").click(function(){

    if( $(".register").css("margin-top") == "200px" ){

       $(".registertrigger").show(); //toggle function here
       return false; //so that the page doesn't refresh

    } else {

       $(".registertrigger").hide();
       return false; //so that the page doesn't refresh

    }

});​
```

Comment: Add the relevant code to this answer, not just a link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you simply need to rework your expression. The problem is you're trying to see if an element is 'clicked', when you should just attach an event handler.

```
$('.loginTrigger').click(function()
{
    if('.register').css('marginTop') === '-200px')
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the click event, i think you want to add an event to the click event...

```
$('.logintrigger').click( function(e){
  if($('.register').css('marginTop') === '-200px'){
    $('.registertrigger').toggle();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `$('.logintrigger').click()`, it is triggering click event.
it should be:

```
if ($('.logintrigger').click(function(){
   if ($('.register').css('marginTop') === '-200px') {
        $('.registertrigger').toggle(
            function () {
               $('.register').stop().animate({'marginTop':'-0px'},200);
               $('#opencloseregister').css({'backgroundPosition':'-20px 0px'});
            }
        );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.logintrigger').on('click', function(){

    if($('.register').css('marginTop')==='200px') {

        $('.registertrigger').toggle( function () {

            $('.register').stop().animate({'marginTop': 0 },200);
            $('#opencloseregister').css({'backgroundPosition':'-20px 0px'});

        });

    }

});
```